# how do I remain the changed value in clojure reframe

Tags: clojurescript, re-frame

Suppose I have a group of buttons and if user clicked a button I want it to change the value from "not clicked" to "clicked" so I have wrote this code

```
(rf/reg-sub
 ::clicked-sub
 (fn [db _]
   (:clicked db)))

(rf/reg-event-db
 ::clicked-event
 (fn [db [_ clicked-numb]]
   (assoc db :clicked clicked-numb)))

(defn button-group [numbers]
  [:div
   (for [number numbers]
     ^{:key number}
     [:button
      {
       :value (if (= number @(rf/subscribe [::clicked-sub])) "clicked" "not clicked")
       :on-click (fn [e] (rf/dispatch [::clicked-event number]))
       }
      ]
     )
   ]
  )
```

The problem is, after the user clicked another button the previous clicked button is changed value from "clicked" to "not clicked". I want it to remain the clicked value for each clicked button how to do that

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your data handling in `db` is too simplistic. Your event is always overwriting the value of `clicked` with the current number, hence the lookup / subcription is always only returning the latest clicked number.

What you instead could do is store a hash-map of numbers / boolean as a value to the `:clicked` key in the `db`. Your event would then update (`assoc-in`) the number to `true`. Of course, you then also need to change your check on the subscription to see if the current number is set to true.